# How do you sneak up on someone in Hitman 2?

Tags: hitman-2-silent-assassin

I understand the the **L1** button is the "sneak button" and that you sneak up behind them extremely slow, but I can't seem to pull off the sneak attack without alerting them first, even in the very first mission.

When I try to sneak up behind the first guy (using **L1**) that comes out of the door (urinating next to the tree), I try to use the anesthetics and right before I get into range to attack him he starts turning around and my alert box starts flashing red, even though I complete the attack successfully in the end. I suppose that one doesn't matter as much since there's no one around, but I assume if I did it correctly the alert box wouldn't flash. However, when I try to sneak up behind The Don (again, using **L1**) with my Fiber Wire, he always turns around and becomes alerted before I can actually strangle him, then after I strangle him his guards barge into the room.

What am I doing wrong with my sneak attacks? They don't seem to be very sneaky if they can get an alert off before you actually get to them... I've tried doing this several times and he is consistently alerted each time. I'm supposedly able to do this without alerting either of them, but I'm obviously missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, apparently the **L1** button has two different functionalities. I thought sneaking required you to *hold* the **L1** button down (nothing in the game ever said otherwise, and most other games I've played require you to hold the button), but holding the button down actually causes you to *crouch* rather than sneak.

What you actually have to do is just *press* the **L1** button (releasing rather than holding) and you enter into sneaking mode, and you press **L1** again to exit out of sneaking mode. While in sneaking mode you are able to sneak up behind people and perform the sneak attacks (like I have been informed is possible).

Using this method I have not encountered any problems with successfully completing the sneak attacks.